# How to weakly reference a single object in Squeak

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

Squeak Smalltalk has support for collections of weak references, but appears to lack a direct equivalent to Java's WeakReference class which supports a weak reference to a single object instance. 
If I'm defining a class of object with several instance variables, one of which I want to be a weak reference, what is the most idiomatic way to do this? Does it make sense to instantiate a WeakArray to hold that single reference, or is there a simpler way that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a WeakArray.

The Squeak VM implements weak references only as indexed variables, whereas instance variables are always strongly referenced. That's why using a one-element WeakArray is the right thing to do.

You could implement your own one-element WeakReference class, but it would not be any more efficient than a WeakArray.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing, with a *standard Squeak image*, there is no direct way to have one instance variable of a class be weak while the others hold strong. However, current VMs such as the [CogVM](http://www.mirandabanda.org/cogblog/about-cog/) are equipped with [Ephemerons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeron), a concept similar, if not more powerful than simple weak references. To my knowledge, the upcoming [SPUR](http://www.mirandabanda.org/cogblog/category/spur/) Squeak image will have Ephemerons by default.

That being said, you can try [an older implementation of Ephemerons](http://web.archive.org/web/20060715094641/http:/isgwww.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/~raab/squeak/packages/Ephemerons/Ephemerons.cs) in Squeak already.